# Full directory path instead of graphical navigation?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, directory

How can I navigate to a folder by writing it's full path?

**/home/john/Desktop/Music** instead of navigating to it from the **base** or from the **Home** folder?

Is there any program that turn this graphical search bar to a "path searching bar"-ish? Just like the one in Windows?

Graphical path:-
[image: Graphical path]

Comment: You can try using different file managers.  I know that Thunar does it with the full path.